# Google Forms - Autofill calculations

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, calculation

I want to create a form that has 2 open-answer questions that are based on numbers (height and weight) in Google Forms and based on these questions an auto-filled field (That is a BMI Calculation based on the 2 inputs from each question) will be shown.

I have looked for a lot of workarounds and couldn't find the best solution, Can anyone advise me on what to use? Should I integrate it with Google Sheets and build a logic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `and based on these questions an auto-filled field (That is a BMI Calculation based on the 2 inputs from each question) will be shown.` Google Forms doesn't have the ability to dynamically take form responses and show a result (the BMI, as in your example). You Maybe there is an add-on that will do this (I don't know). An alternative is to use a web-based form.

Comment: `and couldn't find the best solution` You have mentioned the "best" solution... did you find **"a"** solution/workaround?

Comment: `Should I integrate it with Google Sheets and build a logic?` Yes